# Is it possible to compile the Docker daemon and some Docker containers into a single application?

Tags: docker

I have a system using a few Docker containers. I'd like to make this system available for everyone to use/download.

Is it possible to compile this into a standalone application, such that users don't need to install the Docker daemon and pull and deploy containers? I wish for a one-click installation that hides and encapsulates all the Docker stuff, but looks like any other standalone application.

I'm aware of relatively easy ways of Docker deployment, such as Docker Compose, but I'm really looking for something completely self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker daemon has complex dependencies, it must run as root, and it is a system-level component with a long-running daemon.  You couldn't really embed it in an application.

In principle you could create a distribution package (a `.deb` or RPM file) that depended on the Docker daemon and embedded the metadata to run the application stack as a container.  Once you're doing that, though, it's not any more work and will give a simpler end-user experience to just directly package your application without using Docker.

Docker Desktop is probably an instructive example here.  To put what looks like a friendly interface on Docker, it is a combination of a native non-Docker application, a hidden embedded hypervisor, and a hidden Linux virtual machine actually running Docker.  You'd be looking at that level of packaging to try to get a more portable application distribution, and again there are other tools to create VM images that don't specifically use Docker.